# tkinter not responding when using speech recogmition

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition

so i use tkinter that consist of a window and a button when I press the listen button it started to not responding I've look up for solutions and mostly say that we have to use threads but how to implement it can anyone help ? here is my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def listen():
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            # command = command.lower()
            # if 'bot' in command1:
            #     command1 = command1.replace('bot', '')
            print(command)
    except:
        print("not working")
        pass

def stop():
    pass

form = tk.Tk()
form.geometry('1200x600')
buttonListen = Button(form, text='listen',command=listen)
buttonListen.pack()

form.mainloop()
```

here is my code can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a function which creates a thread and runs it.

Sample code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def listen():
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            # command = command.lower()
            # if 'bot' in command1:
            #     command1 = command1.replace('bot', '')
            print(command)
    except:
        print("not working")
        pass

def listen_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(target= listen)
    thread.start()

form = tk.Tk()
form.geometry('1200x600')
buttonListen = tk.Button(form, text='listen', command=listen_thread)
buttonListen.pack()

form.mainloop()
```

I runned it once and here is the output:

```
Listening...
hello 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

And also dont make 2 imports for the same module.

Use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`